# php insert data and procced

Tags: php, facebook, curl, authentication

I am making a web app that will get your saved passwords from ftp server. This part is working perfectly, now I'm trying to send this data to 3rd site login page.

For example, you have your facebook/google username and password saved encrypted on a server. The app download username and password, decrypt them and display them, so the user can copy/paste it to facebook/google login page.

So, I would like to make this happens automatically. So the app would get username and password and then paste it to login page and proceed.

Right now I managed to get username and password into $username and $password. I also know login page URL $url (https://www.facebook.com/login.php for example). I tried with curl, but i am not sure whether I need to use curl post directly.

Thank you for your time!

EDIT:

I find a way: I copy the source of login page to the server and change login username and password value to "echo $username" and the same for the password. I also add body onload="document.login_form.submit()" to proceed on load.

This method works fine for most of pages, but not for facebook, I get "security error" saying that it is not safe to enter your facebook password on other sites. I guess that they check headers.

Any ideas how to bypass that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use curl then its your web app that would send the data through and be "logged in"; not your users web browser.

You would need to use javascript to make the post request client-side. However, most websites now implement CSRF protection and won't accept the post request if it didn't originate from their website or it doesn't contain the correct CSRF token.

You wouldn't be able to pre-populate the username/password boxes on facebook as that would require your javascript to run on facebook which isn't possible.

Most other services like yours (i.e. roboform) use a browser plugin/extension to do this.

Comment: What if I post username and password into JavaScript funcion that would proceed data to the original login page

Comment: That should work, providing the website(facebook) you are posting the data to doesn't perform any checks on where the post request came from. 

Some sites might error and prevent login due to CSRF protection but might still then populate the form fields with what was posted. Its very site specific however.

Comment: Hmmm what about making a cookie and then just simply header(Location:..) ?

Comment: Again unfortunately due to security you cannot create/modify cookies for other domains/websites.

Comment: So there is no chances that my webapp log the user to Facebook for example ?

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news; but unless you write a browser plugin/extension then its very unlikely.

Comment: Thank you for everything